# Split, Transpose & Print Multiple Records

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Try to take a line item and split & transpose it before doing the same with another line item.

I'm trying to do the split and transpose operation like this

`=transpose(split(c2,","))`

However, this only works for one line item at a time.

Here is what the data looks like and what I'd like the result to look like.

[image]

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

you can try this in the first line and it will give you both of the columns

```
={
ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("º",REPT(A:A&"º",IF(ISBLANK(B:B),"", LEN(B:B)-LEN(REGEXREPLACE(B:B,",",""))+1))),"º")))) ,
ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN(",",IF(ISBLANK(B:B),"",B:B)),","))))
}
```

it parses some blank comma values as well as some empty values.

[image]

What it basically does is:

- **first column**:
  checks the number of times the commas are in the second column, and get that number. Then joins the number of times the left column is repeated with a separator (in this case the separator `º`), like the following: `tvºtvºtv`, then it splits and transposes to show up vertically.
- **second column**:
  checks just checks what is between the commas, and then transposes it, with the same type of string concatenation, this time the delimiter is the comma `,`

**Attention:** it does not work if the second column has 2 followed commas, like the following syntax: `something,,something`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  
                                                                                                                                                I get an error on expanding the formula to a larger dataset.  "Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 290. Actual: 266."

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have any blank cells or joint commas ? like `france,,belgium`

Comment: great answer :)

Comment: Hi Nabais, thanks for all the help. So I some Product line items in the sample set appear as "HDMI (144hz,60hz)" , it looks as though if there's a "," in the Product it ruins the formula! As removing the "," in the data corrects the issue

Comment: check now, with your "HDMI (144hz,60hz)" in the first column, I changed the delimiter of the first column to the `º` symbol, so now if you want to change it to something else just change where you find the `º` symbol

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the data for all countries:

`=transpose(split(join(",",C2:C),","))`

Answer (score 1):

There is a new, relatively simple way to do these problems in Sheets.  Try searching for "using FLATTEN() to unpivot data".  Myself and some other volunteers in the Google Product forums found a new function hidden in the back end of Google sheets and unpivoting data has proven to be it's most useful application.  If you'd like the formula that will work for your particular dataset, condider sharing a sample sheet where the concept can be properly demonstrated.